# Where can I find all DISABLED Unique Keys in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, key, unique

I need to run a routine to find all disabled unique keys in SQL Server, or at least know if a UK exists and is disabled.

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('UK_NAME'UQ') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    PRINT('EXISTS')
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT('DOESNT EXISTS')
END
```

This code doesn't work if a UK is disabled, as the system can't find the UK. Is there a table that I can find all UK even if it is disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use :

```
Select * From sys.indexes
```

Answer (score 1):

You should search for disabled unique indexes:

```
select object_name(object_id) as tbl_name,
       name,
       index_id
from sys.indexes
where is_disabled = 1 and is_unique = 1;
```